# VB6- Open Access DB or one of it's forms with ADO object

Tags: ms-access, vb6

My application written with visual basic 6 and it has an Access database. I want to add a VB form and open the database in this form to make db edits the DB in that. I have this code for oppenning:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = DBEngine.workspaces(0).opendatabase("c:\ss.mdb")
```

I have a form inside that database. This form makes the data insertion process faster. I want to open this access form with my application.
How i should do this??

Note: I have this code that uses Microsoft access 14 object library.

```
Dim appaccess As Access.Application, dbstr As String

On Error Resume Next
Set appaccess = New Access.Application
Set appaccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
dbstr = "c:\ss.mdb"
'Or dbstr="c:\my documents\yourfile.mdb
'put the correct path here.
appaccess.OpenCurrentDatabase dbstr
appaccess.DoCmd.OpenForm "aa", acLayout
appaccess.Visible = True
```

But when i run this code the form appears and after a while it gets  disapear. besides using access object library creates some access version conflicts. So, Although it is not necessary but i prefer to do that with ADO object. Anyway, i' looking for e method to solve my problem.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO provides methods to interact with various data sources.  Although you can use it for Access db files, it doesn't provide methods to utilize Access forms.

With your current approach, you use `CreateObject` to set the object variable `appaccess` to a new Access application instance, then open your form within that instance.  However, when the variable goes out of scope, the Access instance closes and the form disappears.

You might revise your VB6 code to keep the variable in scope until you're finished with the Access instance.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to fit that change into the rest of your code, and I've never used VB6.

Alternatively, you could use the [Shell Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk%28VS.71%29.aspx) to start the Access instance, then use `GetObject()` to set your object variable to that instance.

With the `Shell()` approach, you would need to supply the full path to `MSACCESS.EXE`.  You can find the folder where it's located by reading the registry.  Here's a VBScript sample which does that, and I'm hoping you can adapt it easily for VB6.

```
Option Explicit
Dim MSAccFolder
Dim RegKey
Dim WSHShell

RegKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\" _
    & "CurrentVersion\App Paths\MSACCESS.EXE\Path"
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MSAccFolder= WSHShell.RegRead(RegKey)
WScript.Echo "MS Access Folder: " & MSAccFolder
Set WSHShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use VB, you should abandon the Access Automation stuff and create your form in VB.  Then use ADO to open and work with the Access file.  This is much more efficient than using VB to automatically open an Access form.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is that you're using DAO in that first chunk of code rather than ADO.
Maybe that doesn't matter though because there's no reference to db in your second chunk of code. 
So the first chunk of code looks to be unecessary.

I don't know why you have 2 set statements for appaccess, you don't need the second one.
Also I'd suggest that you comment out the 'on error resume next' statement so you can see which line is causing the error while debugging.